# Secure a Folder in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac

Is there anyway to secure a folder from other's access through password? Preferably free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to create a password protected archive then you could also create a password protected disk image. See [How to create a password-protected (encrypted) disk image in Mac OS X 10.3 or later](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1578). You don't need any 3rd party software for that, it will create a separate file that you can use to store your sensitive data, and when you open it will be opened just like a regular volume (external disk or the like), so you can add/remove files as you see fit.

Answer (score 4):

If you're talking about other user accounts on the system, simply use `chmod(1)`, like this:

```
chmod 700 /my/private/directory
```

That'll give your account read, write, execute access to the directory, and remove those rights from the other users on the system. Of course, root can easily bypass this.